# How to get click location from custom event handler Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to write a custom event handler for CTRL + click in Leaflet.  My problem is that the click location given by the map is different from the click location in the event handler, e.g. `LatLng(51.49174, -0.11639)` from the map click becomes `LatLng(51.50938, -0.126)` in the handler.  The click locations match exactly if the map is the only thing on the page.  Adding some other div elements above the map (like an `<h1>` title) makes the clicks not match.  Panning the map also makes the click locations not match.

I'm wondering if I attached my `L.DomEvent.on()` correctly.  Following the [Leaflet Handlers tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html), my code looks like

```
L.CtrlClickHandler = L.Handler.extend({
  addHooks: function() {
    L.DomEvent.on(document, 'click', this._captureClick, this);
  },

  removeHooks: function() {
    L.DomEvent.off(document, 'click', this._captureClick, this);
  },

  _captureClick: function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      console.log('control click registered at layer ' 
        + map.layerPointToLatLng(new L.point(event.layerX, event.layerY)));
    }
  }
});

// add this to all maps
L.Map.addInitHook('addHandler', 'ctrlClick', L.CtrlClickHandler);
```

Here's a [live example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r68hs922/).

I'm using Leaflet 0.7.7 due to some other dependencies in my code.  Upgrading to Leaflet 1.0.1 makes it match better (e.g., `LatLng(51.49868, -0.1018)` vs. `LatLng(51.4987, -0.1018)`) but the two locations still are not exactly the same.

Am I attaching the L.DomEvent to the correct thing?  Should that be attached to the map div somehow, as opposed to `document`?

*Edit: Thanks to @AlexParij for the suggestion.  I realized that panning the map also makes the clicks not match, with or without `div` elements above the map.  This happens for Leaflet 1.0.1 as well as 0.7.7.  I've tried every combination I can think of, combining different event locations (`event.layerX`, `event.pageX`, `event.clientX`, `event.offsetX`, `event.screenX`, and `event.x`) with projection methods `layerPointToLatLng` and `unproject` but none of them match the map click. Now I'm really confused... Fiddle with these different options and Leaflet 1.0.1: https://jsfiddle.net/c4tkyewz/*

Comment: I would say look at the direction of Layer Point vs Container Point. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69124/leaflet-container-coordinates-vs-layer-coordinates

Comment: @AlexParij Thanks for the suggestion. That made me realize that if I pan the map, the `LatLng` objects are not even close. This holds true without any divs above the map, and for either Leaflet 0.7.7 or Leaflet 1.0.1. I tried all of the options I could think of `event.layerX`, `event.pageX`, `event.clientX`, `event.offsetX`, `event.screenX`, and `event.x,` combined with `layerPointToLatLng`, `unproject`, and `layerPointToContainerPoint` but none of them match. Now I'm really confused... Fiddle with Leaflet 1.0.1: https://jsfiddle.net/c4tkyewz/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL; DR:** use `map.mouseEventToLatLng()` in a custom handler.

---

@AlexParij was correct; I was not using the correct definition of the layer points and container points.  Inside the handler, `event` is different from Leaflet's internal mouse event (where the location is available from `e.latlng`).

I looked through Leaflet's core to find the answer.  Getting the location from `event` requires taking the Mouse Event -> Container Point -> Layer Point -> latLng.  Thankfully, the Leaflet developers already programmed a nice function for this: `mouseEventToLatLng()`.

```
/*
 * This is a custom handler to check if someone has control clicked
 * the map and print the location of the click
 */
L.CtrlClickHandler = L.Handler.extend({
  addHooks: function() {
    L.DomEvent.on(document, 'click', this._captureClick, this);
  },

  removeHooks: function() {
    L.DomEvent.off(document, 'click', this._captureClick, this);
  },

  _captureClick: function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      // translate mouse event to lat/lng (note: `mouseEventToLatLng()` 
      // calls Leaflet's `mouseEventToContainerPoint()` followed by 
      // `containerPointToLayerPoint()` and finally `layerPointToLatLng()`)
      var latlng = map.mouseEventToLatLng(event);
      console.log('Handler detected CTRL + click at ' + latlng);
    }
  }
});

// add this to all maps
L.Map.addInitHook('addHandler', 'ctrlClick', L.CtrlClickHandler);
```

Live example with Leaflet 1.0.1: https://jsfiddle.net/c4tkyewz/1/

Also tested with Leaflet 0.7.7.

---

As a bonus, to access the CTRL key directly from Leaflet's native handling of the click event `map.on('click', function(e) {});`, use `e.originalEvent.ctrlKey`.